# GaussianProcessRegressor Fitting Kernel/Hyperparameters

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gaussian, hyperparameters

good day everyone. I have got the following:

I am using a GaussianProcessRegressor object from the Sklearn library.
After fitting the model, I want to sample points using predict, to get a better idea of what the model looks like so far. But now I do get the issue that it just assumed the points zero anywhere except for the training points.

I reset the alpha value of the Regressor from my initial 1e-5 back to default 1e-10 and the n_restarts_optimizer from 9 back to default zero, my kernel is a Matern kernel with nearly standard settings. Now I do get non-zero values, however I am not sure how to proceed:

I have the following:

```
a = df_reduced.values[0:4, :]
print("a[0,0]: ", a[0,0])
gp.predict(a)
```

Of course this gives me a nice result (since it's the fitting data):

```
a[0,0]:  150.0
Out[47]:

array([[10.4       ],
[ 9.3       ],
[78.39990234],
[78.39990234]])
```

Now I slightly alter the first feature of the first sample in it's initial vicinity:

```
a = df_reduced.values[1:4, :]
a[0, 0] = 151
gp.predict(a)

array([[4.85703698e-254],
[7.83999023e+001],
[7.83999023e+001]])
```

, and for a[0, 0] = 152

```
array([[ 0.        ],
[78.39990234],
[78.39990234]])
```

. So it seems that in most of the area the function is simply zero, which is kind of a problem, because I want to use this for a Gaussian Hyperparameter Optimization minimising globally. Would somebody have a lead how to optimise better?

Btw I am using 16 features, and fitting on 30 samples so far and the output function takes values between 0 and 100.
Parameters are as follows (copy-paste):

```
matern = C(1.0)*Matern(length_scale=1.0, nu=2.5)
gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=matern)
gp.fit(df_reduced.values, Y) # df_reduced.values, because meanwhile we have overwritten X_reduced
```

Thanks already for any lead,

Best regards,

robTheBob86